# Is oscillation seen in data signal or noise?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have some experimental data which is well-fitted by 40 terms of a Fourier series. I want to know if the oscillation exhibited is signal or noise. I evaluated the code shown below to plot my data in the frequency domain:

```
n = 1500; Fs = 5;
data = Table[
5.45918493505274` Sin[0.04772063636154806` t] + 
0.045086627929286` Sin[0.09544127272309612` t] + 
1.8300103126865561` Sin[0.14316190908464418` t] + 
0.05950513311663989` Sin[0.19088254544619224` t] + 
1.1204658721960177` Sin[0.2386031818077403` t] + 
1.2280549940442047` Sin[0.28632381816928837` t] + 
0.5482482136418895` Sin[0.3340444545308364` t] + 
0.1541511622784725` Sin[0.3817650908923845` t] + 
1.3201800186638732` Sin[0.4294857272539325` t] - 
0.02992695120879559` Sin[0.4772063636154806` t] - 
0.03189762652509915` Sin[0.5249269999770286` t] + 
0.2372681539168007` Sin[0.5726476363385767` t] + 
0.8170170094994638` Sin[0.6203682727001247` t] + 
0.39555665907776033` Sin[0.6680889090616728` t] + 
0.022437289985583746` Sin[0.715809545423221` t] - 
0.028460237860878944` Sin[0.763530181784769` t] - 
0.09375141931231344` Sin[0.8112508181463169` t] + 
0.4603754711356663` Sin[0.858971454507865` t] - 
0.18077403034637543` Sin[0.906692090869413` t] + 
0.15912510039844507` Sin[0.9544127272309612` t] - 
0.08353968595635936` Sin[1.0021333635925094` t] + 
0.3616926577088966` Sin[1.0498539999540573` t] - 
0.27510747184055534` Sin[1.0975746363156054` t] + 
0.1575754952689732` Sin[1.1452952726771535` t] - 
0.208483328192468` Sin[1.1930159090387014` t] + 
0.25721738585129583` Sin[1.2407365454002495` t] - 
0.19139970739440976` Sin[1.2884571817617976` t] - 
0.036186536999814646` Sin[1.3361778181233457` t] - 
0.10861411934090208` Sin[1.3838984544848938` t] + 
0.24492671105872857` Sin[1.431619090846442` t] + 
0.01974521283015592` Sin[1.4793397272079898` t] + 
0.0042309416480771495` Sin[1.527060363569538` t] - 
0.06451925752495553` Sin[1.574780999931086` t] + 
0.014720687456469619` Sin[1.6225016362926339` t] + 
0.027150593395034298` Sin[1.670222272654182` t] - 
0.05522496798684457` Sin[1.71794290901573` t] + 
0.18794022781493241` Sin[1.7656635453772782` t] - 
0.014354799094550522` Sin[1.813384181738826` t] + 
0.12345852590875403` Sin[1.8611048181003744` t] - 
0.2394191555149598` Sin[1.9088254544619223` t], 
{t, 0, (n - 1)/Fs, 1/Fs}];
```

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: velocity vs. time]

```
spectrum = 
  AddSpectrumRange[mag, TotalF -> Fs, Centered -> True];
ListLinePlot[spectrum, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Could you please help me. Is the oscillation a true signal or is it noise? Is my code for frequency domain is correct?

Comment: This is rather about underlying math and interpretation, isn't it?

Comment: Since there is a strong spike a little to the right of the DC spike, I would say there is a real signal in there.

Comment: @m_goldberg Could explain more? for having signal, I must have a sharp pic in frequency domain. But it seem to like a white noise because it is like 1/f behavior.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of judgement, but the spike I mentioned doesn't seem to fit into a white noise pattern. Of course, the image you posted is small and I may be mis-reading it. Also, I am not an expert in signal processing.

Comment: @m_goldberg I will be very happy if it is not white noise pattern! I'm not expert in stochastic phenomena! Because of that I want to know others idea.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for your response